# How to prevent asyncValidation when the edit form is populated

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom async validation directive that checks if the input is unique.

In the `create` form it works excellent. The `edit` form is in a modal that pops up when you click a button.

The issue I have is that for some reason, the async validator is fired three times when the modal is shown, but I haven't made any changes to the values. I'm updating the `model` only on `blur` to prevent too many API calls, but I can't figure out why these first three calls are made.

**EDIT:**  I'll post the code if needed, but the asyncValidator is just an API call and it returns a promise. I pass a second value that I need for the validation, but that's all...

**EDIT2:** Here's the code :)

**The directive:**

```
var uniqueWarehouse = [
    "WarehouseService", function(WarehouseService) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            require: "ngModel",
            scope: {
                type: "=uniqueWarehouse",
                id: "=uniqueWarehouseId"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$asyncValidators.uniqueWarehouse = function(value) {
                    if (scope.id != undefined) {
                        return WarehouseService.Check(scope.type, value, scope.id);
                    } else {
                        return WarehouseService.Check(scope.type, value);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
];

AppModule.directive("uniqueWarehouse ", uniqueWarehouse );
```

**Usage:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : ( warehouseForm.$submitted || warehouseForm.title.$touched) && warehouseForm.title.$invalid }">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" ng-maxlength="5" ng-model="warehouse.Title" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-required="true" type="text" unique-warehouse="warehouse.type" unique-warehouse-id="warehouse.id" />
        <div class="has-feedback help-block" ng-show="warehouseForm.title.$pending.uniqueWarehouse">Checking...</div>
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="warehouseForm.title.$error" ng-show="(warehouseForm.$submitted || warehouseForm.title.$touched) && warehouseForm.title.$invalid" role="alert">
            <div ng-message="required">It is required</div>
            <div ng-message="maxlength">Max length exceeded</div>
            <div ng-message="uniqueWarehouse">It already exists</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I'm using Bootstrap UI for the modal.

**EDIT3:**  Is it possible that this is happening, and if yes, how do I avoid it?

1. First call - because the element is shown with the modal the `blur` event is fired
2. Second call - because of the first attribute usage of the directive
3. Third call - because of the second attribute usage of the directive

Comment: I think that posting the code might prove useful to get an answer.

Comment: I just added the code, the validation works fine, but the extra API calls, no clue where they come from. Also I'm using Bootstrap UI, if that has anything to do with it...

Comment: Added a third edit with what I think is the problem